# Redirect Home page to a landing page of category depending on user history

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I am a new in Magento and we need the homepage of our website to be redirected to a landing page for a category page depends on customer history:

we have 2 categories Men and women:

when the customer open our website we will redirect him to women category.
if customer open men category so next time open our website redirect him to men landing page.

something like this website: https://www.zalando.co.uk/men-home/

Thanks to help me to do it.

Answer (score 0):

just put like this

```
 if( $_SESSION['gender'] == "male"){
     header('Location: category.php=male');
 }else{
     header('Location: category.php=female');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply,    It is a magento website and we have 2 categories when you open a category page it is saved and next time redirected to it when open the website homepage.